# Fire TV remote actions using ConnectSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-fire-tv, live-connect-sdk

We are using https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-iOS-FireTV for controlling(Play, Pause, Forward, Rewind) media and performing actions like go Home and Back.

But using these APIs we can control media in **Fire TV’s default media player**. For any other media player(for example VLC or others) these APIs do not work. Also in **ConnectSDK**, in **FireTVService**, other remote control APIs(Home. back etc) do not exists. Is there any way that we can perform these actions?

Comment: I am also searching for the same solution